# How can I create or where can I download (royalty free) sound that goes well with a "bad TV"-effect?

Tags: recommendation

I'm currently doing a movie where I use FCP7s "bad TV"-effect quite a lot to cut within and between scenes. The effect basically emulates a bad TV set where the picture come and go with roll, wave, jitter and color sync artefacts (c.f [Battlefield 3 trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA378g_gD1I)).

Now, I need some sounds to go with these transitions. White noise is a given but I will need clicks, pops and hums to go with that if you understand what I mean. I own the Propellerheads Reason/Record suite so if there are any tutorial for making suitable sounds in these, I'm all ears. Also, recommendations of free sound effects that can be downloaded somewhere are also very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to put a mic close to my speakers and then gently shake and twist the sound cable. Probably not healty for my speakers but a perfect way to generate the sound I wanted. Highly recommended :)

Answer (score 2):

AM radio samples would probably be a good starting point:

http://www.freesound.org/tagsViewSingle.php?id=142